# drop url from url_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, activeadmin

I have a application that I am trying to forward a link to a page from Active Admin. Through Active Admin I have it setup as follows:

```
section "Events" do 

      column "Event Name" do |e|
        link_to e.event_name, url_for(:controller => :sessions, :action => :new, :id => e.event_name)
      end
end
```

When it routes when clicked it still has admin in the url:
  localhost:3000/admin/sessions/new/Sunday%20Evening%20Service

I am trying to drop the admin on the route, so it will look as follows:
  localhost:3000/sessions/new/Sunday%20Evening%20Service

I know this has to do with how ActiveAdmin does urls dynamically, but I can't figure out how to drop the /admin/ part of the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was not with Active Admin because it creates url's dynamically. I had to use the following code:

```
link_to e.event_name, new_session_path(:id => e.event_name)
```